# Set height of a Div by Offset was jerky/lagging

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, scroll, offset

in my web app I try to set a height of a div on scroll event to make UI effect and parallax,
when I scroll over the top, the Div gets bigger, and when I scroll to bottom page the Div gets smaller for a parallax effect.

I use **@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])** for trigger the scroll, its work but the result was so jerky with freeze frame, with random delay...

someone has an idea of why is so randomly buggy ? Or a angular library can do that with performance optimisation ?

component.html :

```
    <div id="header" class="header" >
      <div class="coverBackgroundGradiantUp">  </div>
        <div class="coverBackgroundGradiantDown">
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="panel" class="panel" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
{...bodypage...}
</div>
```

component.ts :

```
export class ProfilComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }


  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  scrollHandler(event) {
    console.log(window.pageYOffset)
    const offset = window.pageYOffset
    if (offset < -1) {
      document.getElementById("headerHeight").style.width = String((100 - offset/6)+ "%");
      document.getElementById("headerHeight").style.height = String( 151 - offset + "px");
    } else if (offset < 151) {
      document.getElementById("headerHeight").style.height = String( 151 - offset + "px");
    } else if (offset > 151) {
      document.getElementById("headerHeight").style.height = String(0 + "px");
    }
  }
```

component.scss :

```
.header{
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;

  background-image: url("../../../../../assets/exempleCover.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  width: 100%;
  height: 151px;
  top: 59px;
  background-color: red;
}

......

.panel{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 146px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

[the scroll laggy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKc6y.gif)

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to events like that angular runs change detection after every callback execution (every time DOM event is fired and callback is executed). You need to subscribe to DOM event manually outside of angular zone.

The simplest way to do that is to:

inject `NgZone` into your component:

```
constuctor(private readonly ngZone: NgZone) { }
```

subscribe to scroll event in `ngOnInit()` via native browser api (you can use `Renderer2` as well):

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler);
});
```

don't forget to unsubscribe from event in `ngOnDestroy()`:

```
window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler);
```

change the `scrollHandler` function to lambda format, to bind context and to be able to unsubscribe in the future:

```
scrollHandler = (event) => {
  console.log(window.pageYOffset);
  const offset = window.pageYOffset;
  ...
}
```

I wrote the code in editor, so there may be some typo.

Comment: hks very much Amir , unfortunately when i try to use renderer2 and i have an error : 

i have zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined cuz this.panel is undefined.